# OBIEE - cannot create aggregated values

Tags: obiee

I am trying to create aggregated fields for OBIEE reporting .. I am not able to do it even in Oracle BI Admin Tool ...

When I double click AMOUNT in Business Model & Mapping layer and set aggretation to SUM (column type: DOUBLE) ... save repo load in Enterprise Manager (EM) and check it in OBIEE ... it shows me null values only ..

If I check in EM server logs (which query did it generate) there is no amount in select ...

I've tried to create it directly inside OBIEE -> Table edit form -> Variable options -> Aggregation rule .. SUM

But nothing happend.. I can see values in detail, not grouped and SUMed by dimension :(

Do you have any idea/suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OBI will select CAST(NULL AS DOUBLE) or something along those lines (as shown in the query log) when your logical model is invalid. Check that you have created your model correctly.